# Android App crashes when I try to capture from EditText

Tags: android, android-intent, menu, crash

So I am trying to make a contact form in an Alert Dialogue box which opens from a menu option. I have 3 EditText fields in my form and in my Main.java I read from those fields when the Send button in form is pressed and then I start an Email intent, or at least thats what it is supposed to do. Right now the app crashes as soon as I press the send button. Now I have troubleshooted the problem and it doesnt seem to be in the intent but it occurs when I read from the EditText fields. The code works fine when I take out the EditText reading part and just put filler information in its place, but I need this to work with the EditTexts. Thank you.
My whole code for the option in the menu:

```
case R.id.menu_feedback:

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle(R.string.menu_feedback);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

// Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
// Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.feedback, null));
// Add the buttons
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.send, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
           // User clicked OK button
           final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
           String name = nameField.getText().toString();
           final EditText emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextEmail);
           String email = emailField.getText().toString();
           final EditText feedbackField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextFeedbackBody);
           String feedback = feedbackField.getText().toString();
           final CheckBox responseCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxResponse);
           boolean bRequiresResponse = responseCheckbox.isChecked();

           /* Create the Intent */
           final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

           /* Fill it with Data */
           emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
           emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, R.string.send_email);
           emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
           emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, feedback);

           /* Send it off to the Activity-Chooser */
           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
           dialog.dismiss();

       }
   });
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               dialog.dismiss();
           }
       });

// create alert dialog
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

// show it
alertDialog.show();

return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I assume your all EditTexts are written in `feedback layout` file for AlertDialog,

```
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feedback, null);
builder.setView(dialogView );
```

And Edittext are like,

```
// User clicked OK button
final EditText nameField = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
String name = nameField.getText().toString();
final EditText emailField = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.EditTextEmail);
String email = emailField.getText().toString();
final EditText feedbackField = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.EditTextFeedbackBody);
String feedback = feedbackField.getText().toString();
```

Actually, when you are inflating any view and you have to use child views of that views then you have to use the reference of that view and `findViewById()` method. So in your case, `dialogView.findViewById();`

Comment: so everytime i inflate a view, i should inflate a child view instead of the original thing?

Comment: No, you have to inflate only main View, as you are inflating for your **AlertDialog** then using reference of that view you have to define other views which are child views of inflated views.

Answer (score 1):

use `builder` or `inflater` instances for Accessing EditText or other views from AlertDialog as :

```
 builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.send, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           // User clicked OK button
   final EditText nameField = (EditText)inflater. findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
   String name = nameField.getText().toString();
   final EditText emailField = (EditText)inflater. 
                                                 findViewById(R.id.EditTextEmail);
   String email = emailField.getText().toString();
   final EditText feedbackField = (EditText)inflater. 
                                          findViewById(R.id.EditTextFeedbackBody);
   String feedback = feedbackField.getText().toString();
// your code here..
```

Comment: i am trying this but it is telling me
"The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type LayoutInflater"

Comment: sorry if i m being noobish

Comment: @Zaid : not an issue use use builder instead of inflater

Comment: @Zaid : as  `final EditText nameField = (EditText)builder. findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);`

Comment: thanks for quick reply, which is better implementation yours or the one above?

Comment: @Zaid : you can chose any one both is right way to access UI elements from AlertDialog

Comment: @Zaid : if this answer help u in solving current issue then mark it as answer . Thanks